# Como Salvar itens da Datagridview dentro de uma coluna?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, microsoft-access, datagridview

Estou criando um formulário de Orçamentos, parecido com este da foto:

[image: Tela de Orçamentos]

Como podem ver, no botão Novo, gero uma nova linha no banco com o número do orçamento no campo `Código` e o cliente no campo `NomeCliente`. Porém, na hora de adicionar as peças e serviços, não tenho ideia de como faço. Eles estão no `datagrid` com vários campos Código da peça, Nome, unidades, valor unitário, Desconto e valor total.

Ao terminar de adicionar todos os itens na `datagrid` através do formulário de produtos e serviços, não consigo inserir as linhas dentro do banco, para quando consultar novamente o orçamento elas aparecerem na própria `datagrid`.

Alguém puder me dar uma ajuda com ideia de como fazer? Estou ainda para começar o projeto.

então me vem a dúvida:

Qual banco usar? Teria alguma maneira de fazer isso com Access 2003, ou alguma versão mais recente? Ou devo inserir uma base de dados em SQL Server?

Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este é um caso clássico de mestre-detalhe. [Há uma explicação bastante rica de como fazer isso aqui](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/masterdetail/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs), mas podemos esmiuçar um pouco mais a resposta.

Access nunca é muito recomendável para um banco de dados, a não ser que haja um ótimo motivo pra isso (legado, por exemplo). [A alternativa mais interessante ao Access é o SQL Server LocalDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh510202.aspx), que é praticamente um SQL Server portátil, e cujo arquivo de dados pode ser importado em uma instância do SQL Server de forma transparente.

Comment: iria usar Access pois sera uma aplicação pequena , apenas de 1 usuario , e apenas para orçamentos , obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Cigano Morrison Mendez! Comecei a fazer um sistema para 1 usuário também. A princípio estava acessando o Access mesmo, mas agora que você aconselhou estou buscando outras opções... Você pode me dizer porque o Access não é muito recomendado? Agradeço desde já!